# Can I format part of a string using just CSS?

Tags: css, html

Given HTML that looks like this:

```
<td class="n">1234.56</td>
```

I would like, using only CSS (without having to use, say, a `<span>` element in the HTML), to format the number with the last two digits (or, in general, *characters*) diminished in size.

My goal is to write a CSS stylesheet rule for the unadorned HTML above that behaves as if I had this:

```
<style>
.diminish { font-size: 50% }
</style>
<td class="number">1234.<span class="diminish">56</span></td>
```

Comment: You kind could but not really, if the content is always 1234.56 then you could use `:before` or `:after` to manipulate it but I am sure you have different content

Comment: `::before` and `::after` insert a fake element before and after the current one, so it wouldn't select the digits which are part of the element. The only CSS selector which can select characters is ::first-letter which selects the first letter of a paragraph. You have no choice but to edit the html, sorry.

Comment: What if you changed it to have a space before the decimal point? Is that doable?

Comment: @SmokeyPHP, I *could* (with some pretty weird rendering code)..., but I wonder what you're driving at?

Comment: Just thinking about white space wrapping with a hidden overflow and then same again for the other part in a pseudo element. You'd set the size small but to allow horizontal overflow and turn off word breaking, then hide the bottom wrapping (the decimals), then try and get just the second line in the `:after` pseudo element with the same technique

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not possible with pure CSS. Only html as you pointed out or Javascript.